# Handler/Runnable not working with loop

Tags: android, multithreading, while-loop, handler

I am trying to get my TextView to update in a separate thread so that it doesn't slow down my UI. It works, but when I add in a while loop to control it, it hangs the program in a black screen.

Code:

```
handler.post(new Runnable(){
           @Override
            public void run() {

            while(media[6].isPlaying()) {

            TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerT);   

            myText.setText(getTimeString(media[1].getCurrentPosition()));        


            handler.postDelayed(this,10);
                                        }
        }

    });
```

I thought that the runnable creates a new thread, meaning that this wouldn't happen? Or am I going badly wrong?

Comment: When you post a `Runnable` using a `Handler` it gets executed on the main thread. `Runnable` is just an interface... it does not contain any hidden code other than the code you write when implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your black screen is because you are running an arbitrary duration while loop on the event dispatch thread: never do this. For something of this sort you want to use AsyncTask or start your Runnable in a separate thread and then use View.post to send the timer updates only.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) class like below:

```
// Function arguments are in milliseconds. 
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(6000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        // Do your stuff here.

        TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerT);

        myText.setText(getTimeString(media[1].getCurrentPosition()));
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("done!");
    }
}

timer.start();
```